# How to reliably access root tag's namespace declarations and attributes using lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

In the following example, is there a way to either:

1. only print the root `REQ-IF` tags's complete attributes without having lxml to print the whole XML document
   or
2. to enumerate the root tag's namespaces and attributes in the same order as they appear in an XML document?

My goal is to get precisely this string and nothing else:

```
<REQ-IF xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20101201" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20110401/reqif.xsd reqif.xsd http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml driver.xsd">
```

In the code below, I can either print the whole XML document or access independently the `nsmap` and `attrib` properties. I can also imagine making a deep copy of a document tree, removing the children nodes and calling `tostring()` on that parent node only but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution to just get the exact XML string of the parent tag without accessing its child tags or hacking on the tree structure?

```
import io

from lxml import etree

reqif_content = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<REQ-IF xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20101201" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20110401/reqif.xsd reqif.xsd http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml driver.xsd">
  <THE-HEADER>
    <REQ-IF-HEADER IDENTIFIER="3dd1a60c-59d1-11da-86ca-4bda04a730ce">
      <COMMENT>Embedded OLE object with multiple representation forms.</COMMENT>
      <CREATION-TIME>2005-05-23T12:00:00+02:00</CREATION-TIME>
      <SOURCE-TOOL-ID>Manually written</SOURCE-TOOL-ID>
      <TITLE>Test data RIF72</TITLE>
    </REQ-IF-HEADER>
  </THE-HEADER>
</REQ-IF>
"""

xml_reqif_root = etree.parse(
    io.BytesIO(bytes(reqif_content, "UTF-8"))
)

print(etree.tostring(xml_reqif_root.getroot(), pretty_print=True).decode("utf8"))
print("nsmap:")
print(xml_reqif_root.getroot().nsmap)
print("attrib:")
print(xml_reqif_root.getroot().attrib)
```

In the output, it is clear that I get a full XML which I don't want and I get some non-identical representation of the namespaces and attributes:

```
<REQ-IF xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20101201" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20110401/reqif.xsd reqif.xsd http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml driver.xsd">
  <THE-HEADER>
    <REQ-IF-HEADER IDENTIFIER="3dd1a60c-59d1-11da-86ca-4bda04a730ce">
      <COMMENT>Embedded OLE object with multiple representation forms.</COMMENT>
      <CREATION-TIME>2005-05-23T12:00:00+02:00</CREATION-TIME>
      <SOURCE-TOOL-ID>Manually written</SOURCE-TOOL-ID>
      <TITLE>Test data RIF72</TITLE>
    </REQ-IF-HEADER>
  </THE-HEADER>
</REQ-IF>
nsmap:
{None: 'http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20101201', 'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'}
attrib:
{'{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}schemaLocation': 'http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20110401/reqif.xsd reqif.xsd http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml driver.xsd'}
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Namespace declarations are not really attributes; they just look like attributes.

Comment: I am writing a ReqIF parser and unparser in Python. One of my goals is to ensure a complete round-trip: parse a ReqIF document, unparse it, and get a 100% identical output.

Comment: The only way I can think of to get the exact wanted output is to not parse as XML: `root_start_tag = io.StringIO(reqif_content).readlines()[1].strip()`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! It looks like the best way for me now is to clone the tree, remove children, and only dump the XML using tostring.

Comment: That is probably better. XML consists of elements, not lines.